# how to display multiple rave reports at the same time

Tags: delphi

i have an interface in which it is possible for two or more different forms to be opened at the same time (handling them from a taskbar) and these forms may be connected with a rave project and as a result the user is able to take a relative report. The problem is that when the window with the rave report's print preview is opened,the user cannot do anything else til he closes the preview window. Is there a way for the user to be able to return/go to another form and open another report's print preview while the first one is still open??
any idea would be appreciated.. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [make your own preview window](http://www.nevrona.com/rave/tips/rvtip74.html), and show it non-modally.

Comment: there is no property ,for example, at the RpPreviewForm that could solve this, isn't there?is that the only way?thanks a lot!

Comment: I am pretty sure that the preview window follows the norms of Delphi dialog box components and would be shown in a modal window. But if you put a preview pane in a form of your own design, then you have full control.

Comment: That was very helpful, it works fine.. one more question pls, is there a way to set the RpFormStatus as modal form (in order not to be possible for the user to click anywhere else and loose the focus before it completes its work)? tnxxxx